# Creating a Meme Generator with addEventListener (no canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm completing the following assessment:

### -User should be able to submit a form on the page to generate a new meme on the page, and should be able to add multiple memes to the page by submitting the form multiple times.
-Users should be able to click on a button to remove a meme from the page.
-When the meme form is submitted, values in the form inputs should be cleared

My code is not displaying the meme. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I've been staring at it forever so any help is appreciated.

```js
let img = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
let form = document.querySelector("form");
const button = document.querySelector("button");
form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const meme = document.createElement("div");
    const textTop= document.createElement("div");
    const textBottom = document.createElement("div");
    const img = document.createElement("img");

    img.src = document.getElementById("imageUrl").value;
    textTop.classList.add("textTop");
    textTop.innerHTML = document.getElementById("topText").value;

    textBottom.classList.add("textBottom");
      textBottom.innerHTML = document.getElementById("bottomText").value;
      

    meme.classList.add("meme");
    meme.append(textTop);
    meme.append(textBottom);
    meme.append(img);
    let memeLocation = document.getElementById("location");
    memeLocation.append(meme);

form.reset()
   
    })
```

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    background-color: lightcyan;
}

h1,
h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
    background-color: rgb(43, 159, 226);
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: none;
}

.meme {
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    border: 0.08rem solid black;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    position: relative;
}
.textTop {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 30px;
    color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 3;
}

.textBottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 30px;
    color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 3;
}

.meme img {
    max-width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <h1>Meme Generator</h1>
    <h2>Complete the form below to instantly create your meme!</h2>
    <form>
        Image Url: <input id="imageUrl" type="text" placeholder="Input the URL for the Meme Image" required>
        Top Text: <input id="topText" type="text" placeholder="(Optional) Text to display on top of image">
        Bottom Text: <input id="bottomText" type="text" placeholder="(Optional) Text to display on bottom of image">
        <button type="submit" style="float: right;">Add Meme</button>
      </form>


      <div id="location"></div>
```

Comment: I added your code as a snippet and the first meme does work. So are you have a problem showing all memes or just the second one? Check out the snippet to test it.

Comment: Seems to work for me when I run the Snippet (demo code, in your question); what's the specific problem you're having?

Comment: Is there a reason it would work in the snippet but not in Chrome? Bc thats the issue I'm having. I see you're correct that it works fine in the snippet, but when I try to open the page in Chrome nothing appears.

Comment: After adding the DOMContentLoaded event listener it works! Thanks for pointing out the snippet was working, that helped narrow it down!